# Unix: how to read line's original content from file

Tags: echo, cut, trim

I have a data file, the content is as follows:

```
department: customer service  section: A
department: marketing         section: A
department: finance           section: A
```

When I read each line, I would extract the department name using `cut` command. Unfortunately, the program will automatically `trim` all redundant space and thus I cut the department name incorrectly.

```
cat dept.dat | while read line
do
    echo $line
    echo $line | cut -c 12-29
done
```

e.g. the original line is:

```
department: marketing         section: A
```

While the program treats this line as:

```
department: marketing section: A
```

How can I read the line without trimming all the redundant space?

Comment: Becuase I need to implement some more business logic, it is required to read the file line by line

Comment: See [this wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). It has all the common bash pitfalls that you should avoid. The one you mentioned is just a minor example of a very large set of problems you may encounter while scripting in bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are losing the spaces when you expand `$line`. Put double quotes around your variable expansion and you'll preserve the spaces:

```
$ cat dept.dat | while read line
> do
>     echo "$line"
>     echo "$line" | cut -c 12-29"
> done
department: customer service  section: A
 customer service 
department: marketing         section: A
 marketing        
department: finance           section: A
 finance
```

Comment: +1. I'd also recommend setting `IFS` to the null string, so that leading whitespace is not discarded, and specifying the `-r` flag to `read`, so that backslashes are not processed/discarded. That is: instead of `while read line`, I'd recommend writing `while IFS= read -r line`. It's more verbose, but it guarantees that *no* mangling will happen. (Unless the line contains null bytes . . .)

Answer (score 1):

#### regex matching

You can also achieve something similar using `sed`:

```
$ cat dept.dat | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  echo "$line" | sed -e 's/.*: \(.*\)  .*/\1/'
done
```

You could also use `awk`:

```
$ cat dept.dat | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  echo "$line" | awk '{sub(/.*nt: /,""); sub(/  .*/,""); print }'
done
```

You could also use `grep`:

```
$ cat dept.dat | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  echo "$line" | grep -oP '(?<=: ).*(?=  )'
done
```

**NOTE:** The `grep` solution assumes a recent version of `grep` that includes PCRE (Perl regular expression support).

The main difference in these solutions vs. `cut` are that they match based on patterns where the `cut` solution assumes a more rigid structure (specific character positions) to the input data.

#### static positional matching

An alternative to using `cut` is to use `awk`'s `substr` function:

```
$ cat dept.dat | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  echo "$line" | awk '{print substr($0,13,16)}'
done
```